# Productos realacionados con 3 tablas - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Buenas estoy intentando sacar los complementos relacionados pero no consigo sacar la info de la tercera tabla donde están los nombres de los complementos.

Tengo tres tablas:

**Productos**

-Donde las relaciones las hago con su columna `id`.

**Producto_complementos:
-Aquí guardo los productos con sus respectivos complementos, donde se relaciona con la tabla productos a través de la columna `producto_producto_id` y tiene otra columna donde se relaciona con la tabla complementos que se llama `complemento_complemento_id`.

**Complementos**
-Donde están almacenados todos los complementos que están en la bd. Su columna para las relaciones se llama `id`, pero también tiene otros campos como; name, foto y alguno más.

Bien una vez en la ficha del producto quiero sacar los complementos que tiene ese producto. Esto son mis modelos:

**Modelo producto**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function complementos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Producto_complemento', 'producto_producto_id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Producto_complemento**

```
class Producto_complemento extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'producto_complementos';

    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Producto', 'id');
    }

    public function infoComplemento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Complemento', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo complemento**

```
class Complemento extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'complementos';

    public function complementos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Producto_complemento', 'complemento_complemento_id');
    }
}
```

Lo intento iterar del siguiente modo, pero sin éxito:

```
@foreach ($productos->complementos as $comp)
   <li>{{ $comp->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Si en lugar de poner `name` que es lo que quiero sacar pongo `{{ $comp->complemento_complemento_id }}` me saca los complementos que tiene ese producto, pero quiero sacar el nombre, creo que no conecto bien con la tercera tabla.

Comment: Hola @BetaM puse `belongsToMany` en el modelo de Producto_complemento, pero sigue sin sacar nada, te referias ahí?

Comment: Si sacar los datos de la tabla intermedia, pero los nombres están en la tercera tabla `complementos` @BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunos comentarios:

- Dado que tienes una relación de muchos a muchos y los datos que desean vienen de la tabla *pivote* entonces la relación de Eloquent que ocupas es [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Tus modelos quedarían así:

Modelo Complemento:

```
class Complemento extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey='id'; //esto es opcional, si se llama id entonces no lo ocupas
    protected $table = 'nombre_tabla_complemento'; //declara el nombre de la tabla
    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class, 'nombre_tabla_pivote', 'llave_foranea_modelo_complemento', 'llave_foranea_modelo_producto');
    }
}
```

Modelo Producto:

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey='id'; //esto es opcional, si se llama id entonces no lo ocupas
    protected $table = 'nombre_tabla_producto'; //declara el nombre de la tabla
    public function complementos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Complemento::class, 'nombre_tabla_pivote', 'llave_foranea_modelo_producto', 'llave_foranea_modelo_complemento');
    }
}
```

- Dado que estás según to código tratando de obtener todos los productos con todos sus complementos, entonces necesitas 2 ciclos foreach

  - Uno para los datos de los productos
  - Otro para los datos de los complementos
- Idealmente también debes usar el método (*aunque esto es opcional*) [**`has`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) para solamente obtener los productos que estén relacionados con al menos un complemento
- En el segundo `foreach` debes indicar `$variable->relacion as $elemento` para que puedas acceder a la relación de productos con complementos
- Declara las relaciones como plural, es decir complementos y productos

Tu consulta sería:

```
$data = Producto::has('complementos')->with('complementos')->get();
```

Y en la vista la iteración sería así:

```
    @foreach($data as $elemento) 
        {{ $elemento->name_complemento }}
        @foreach($elemento->complementos as $complement)
            {{ $complement->name }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Observaciones:

- Tu tabla pivote no sigue las convenciones, revisa [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Esta respuesta se basa en un ejemplo en local funcional, revisa y modifica los nombres de:

  - Los modelos
  - Las relaciones
  - Los nombres de las columnas que deseas recuperar en cada uno de los ciclos `foreach` para que los adaptes a tus necesidades

**EDICIÓN**

Si tratas de obtener un solo producto con todos sus complementos entonces tu consulta debe estar así:

```
$data = Product::has('complementos')->with('complementos')->findOrFail($idProducto);
return view('tu-vista', ["data" => $data]);
```

En lugar del método `get()` usaremos el método [findOrFail](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) donde le pasaremos como argumento un id que identifique el producto que queremos encontrar

Posterior en la vista iterarás los valores así:

```
<!--
    Aquí obtenemos directo el nombre del producto, como filtramos para solo obtener uno entonces no se hace necesario que usemos ningún foreach para iterar
-->
{{ $data->name_producto }}

<!--
    Aquí si necesitamos un ciclo foreach para iterar todos los complementos que obtuvimos y que estan asociados al producto que filtramos en la consulta
-->
@foreach($data->complementos as $complement)
    {{ $complement->name }} <!--aqui imprimimos las columnas de la tabla complementos-->
@endforeach
```

Comment: Estupendo! bravo ahora si! gracias por la paciencia @BetaM todo solucionado marco la respuesta como la correcta! gracias!!! ;)

Comment: Perdona @BetaM me surge una duda, ahora la vista espera siempre tener complementos pero hay productos que puede ser que no los tenga, que puedo hacer, un `if` o algo así? gracias

Comment: Lo solucione con un if y parece que funciona

Comment: Es verdad utilice ya el `forelse` gracias @BetaM